# Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8' in ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 and trying to install tensorflow. Nvidia driver version is `Driver Version: 470.63.01`.
First, i have installed cuda 11.0 and checked it installation via following command

`cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt`

It output CUDA Version 11.0.207.

Next i installed cudnn

```
tar -xzvf cudnn-11.0-linux-x64-v8.0.5.39
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/include 
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64 
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

I also checked cuda files with this command
`ls /usr/local |grep cuda`
which result in

cuda
cuda-11.0

Cudnn files are tested by

```
ls /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.8*
```

and output is

```
/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.8
/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.8.0.5
```

Then i installed tensorflow
`pip install tensorflow==2.4.0`
but when i run

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

It did not get GPU and error is `Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue. From your code snippet I see that you are referencing two different CUDA locations:

- `/usr/local/cuda/`
- `/usr/local/cuda-11.0/`

So you might double-check if that causes an issue.

From [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38351) I learned that TF reads the system information about available CUDA from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Multiple CUDA versions are installed on the system I am using. Thus, exporting these paths explicitly fixed the issue for me:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-11.0
```

Of course, you would need to adapt the path to your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and in my case I was forced to reinstall all nvidia/cuda components and Torch libs and reinstall them. After I did that, my training process goes fine using my 1070Ti GPU. Use [this](https://gist.github.com/MihailCosmin/affa6b1b71b43787e9228c25fe15aeba#file-cuda_11-8_installation_on_ubuntu_22-04) instructions,hope helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8
```